# Scala: return a value with a chance?

Tags: scala, return, probability

I'd like to model a function which would return a set of values with weighed probability. Something like this:

```
25% => return "a"
25% => return "b"
50% => return "c"
```

Most of the documentation I've seen so far is rather heavy and delves quickly into scientific depths without examples, thus the question:
What's the easiest way to achieve this?

EDIT: I am using Gatling DSL to write a load test with weighed actions. The built-in weighed distribution has a limitation (won't work in loops), which I would like to avoid by having an own implementation. The snippet looks like this:

```
  override def scenarioBuilder = scenario(getClass.getSimpleName)
    .exec(Account.create)
    .exec(Account.login)
    .exec(Account.activate)
    .exec(Loop.create)
    .forever(getAction)

  def getAction = {
    // Here is where I lost my wits
    // 27.6% => Log.putEvents
    // 18.2% => Log.putBinary
    // 17.1% => Loop.list
    // 14.8% => Key.listIncomingRequests
    // rest => Account.get
  }
```

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?  Just some hardcoded values with hardcoded probabilities? Or a function that takes in a set of possible values with probabilities for each?

Comment: Could you tell a little bit more about how you expect this to be done? You could do it java-like, or with more functional-style. We cannot help you if you don't tell us what kind of code you're writing.

Comment: @puhlen hardcoded probabilities with hardcoded values will do, this is not something I expect to change any time.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet frankly, I don't care, whatever is the faster/easier way will do.

Comment: @EugeneA just use the Random class to generate random values and return based on that.Could you post your code and what specifically you are having trouble with?

Comment: @puhlen Added the code snippet to the question. I could not think of a clean solution with Random without ugly looking math hacks.

Comment: This reminds me of  the `frequency` function for generators in Scalacheck https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, clean and ready:

```
randomSwitchOrElse(
    27.6 -> exec(Log.putEvents),
    18.2 -> exec(Log.putBinary))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the shortest version of a generic function to choose based on probabilities:

```
val probabilityMap = List(0.25 -> "a", 0.25 -> "b")
val otherwise = "c"

def getWithProbability[T](probs: List[(Double, T)], otherwise: T): T = {
  // some input validations:
  assert(probs.map(_._1).sum <= 1.0)
  assert(probs.map(_._1).forall(_ > 0))

  // get random in (0, 1) range
  val rand = Random.nextDouble()

  // choose by probability:
  probs.foldLeft((rand, otherwise)) {
    case ((r, _), (prob, value)) if prob > r => (1.0, value)
    case ((r, result), (prob, _)) => (r-prob, result)
  }._2
}
```

`foldLeft` keeps advancing over the probabilities until it finds one where `r` is smaller; If we haven't found it, we move onto the next probability with `r-prob` to "remove" the part of the range we've already covered.

**EDIT**: an equivalent but perhaps easier to read version can use `scanLeft` to create *cumulative* ranges before "searching" for the range within which `rand` has landed:

```
def getWithProbability[T](probs: List[(Double, T)], otherwise: T): T = {
  // same validations..

  // get random in (0, 1) range
  val rand = Random.nextDouble()

  // create cumulative values, in this case (0.25, a), (0,5, b)
  val ranges = probs.tail.scanLeft(probs.head) {
    case ((prob1, _), (prob2, value)) => (prob1+prob2, value)
  }
  ranges.dropWhile(_._1 < rand).map(_._2).headOption.getOrElse(otherwise)
}
```